# Why does H2O Stacked ensemble return only a single class probability?

Tags: machine-learning, h2o

I noticed that unlike H2O GBM that returns two class probabilities (p0 and p1), H2O Stacked ensemble only returns a single class probability. Can anyone explain why is this the case and does this probability correspond to p1 by default?

**H2O stacked ensemble prediction:**[image]

**H2O GBM model prediction:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have accidentally trained a regression model using the Stacked Ensemble (regression predictions are just a single column).  For H2O to do classification, you need to ensure that your response column is a "factor" (aka "enum") type, otherwise H2O will do regression.

Comment: I have converted the target binary variable to factor using asfactor(). As this is a classification problem, I have used H2ORandomForestEstimator and H2OXGBoostEstimator as my base estimators and H2OGradientBoostingEstimator as a meta-estimator inside H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator object.

Comment: I figured out the issue. I mistakenly converted a different target column to factor type. Thanks for the clarification.